# Unable to add YouTube playlist using v3 api

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I've been working on this for a bit and can't seem to get past this block.

I can create the service using the v3 api and can get some user specific data back but when it comes to adding playlists I'm getting an error that I can't seem to get around.

--EDIT-- Passing the object instead of the jsonified string will work.

```
json_obj = {'snippet':{'title':title}}
#json_str = json.dumps(json_obj)
playlist = self.service.playlists().insert(part='snippet, status', body=json_obj)
playlist.execute()
```

Which gives me something like this:

Request Headers:

```
{'Authorization': u'Bearer TOKEN',
 'accept': 'application/json',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'content-length': '73',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'user-agent': 'google-api-python-client/1.0'}
```

Request Body:

```
'"{\\"snippet\\":{\\"title\\":\\"2013newTest\\"}}"'
```

Response Headers:

```
{'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
 'date': 'Tue, 08 Jan 2013 01:40:13 GMT',
 'expires': 'Tue, 08 Jan 2013 01:40:13 GMT',
 'server': 'GSE',
 'status': '400',
 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block'}
```

Response Body:

```
'{"error": {
   "errors": [
     {"domain": "youtube.parameter",
      "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
      "message": "No filter selected.", 
      "locationType": "parameter",
      "location": ""}
             ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "No filter selected."}}'
```

And the response the library raises as a result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playlist.py", line 190, in <module>
    yt_pl.add_playlist('2013newTest')
  File "playlist.py", line 83, in add_playlist
    playlist.execute()
  File "oauth2client/util.py", line 121, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "apiclient/http.py", line 693, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?alt=json&part=snippet%2C+status&key=[KEY] returned "No filter selected.">
```

The only thing I could find where someone was getting the same error was only vaguely related and was in C#.  Has anyone been able to add playlists using v3 in python and if so can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to get this working first in the Google APIs Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/ I've made a similar (authenticated) request using the explorer and gotten a 200 OK.

Comment: I'm able to get a valid response from there which leads me to think that it's something either in their lib or something that I'm doing wrong.  I can't seem to find anything referencing a filter in either their docs or in the json that the discovery process uses to create the object itself.

Comment: How are you authenticating the object? Have you tried executing without dumping the object to JSON?

Comment: Using their oAuth2 library - using OAuth2WebServerFlow with client_secrets downloaded from the site and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube as the scope.  I'm manually authorizing it for the account I'm using to test then cacheing the creds.  

I can get valid "authorized" data back - like using the mine=True parameter for the playlists.list.

For example, this works fine:

get_all_playlists = self.service.playlists().list(part='id, snippet, status', mine=True)
pl_data = get_all_playlists.execute()

Comment: Turns out that fixes it - if you pass it in directly instead of converting to a json string it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The payload sent in `body` must be an object which can be serialized into JSON.

This is because the default `JsonModel` [used for your request](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/apiclient/model.py?r=30bef71e91a278dc769340e5ac9668f5fdd4f654#256) body has a `serialize` method which always `dumps` to json:

```
class JsonModel(BaseModel):
  ...
  def serialize(self, body_value):
    if (isinstance(body_value, dict) and 'data' not in body_value and
        self._data_wrapper):
      body_value = {'data': body_value}
    return simplejson.dumps(body_value)
```

So when you pass in already JSON serialized string, you get double serialized.

For example:

```
>>> json.dumps({'a': 'b'})
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.dumps('{"a": "b"}')
'"{\\"a\\": \\"b\\"}"'
```

Which is essentially what happened to your request body:

```
'"{\\"snippet\\":{\\"title\\":\\"2013newTest\\"}}"'
```

Could you point to some documentation that led you astray so it can be fixed?